# Title: Python itertools.groupby gives inconsistent counts when printing only the counts

Tags: python, itertools-groupby

I'm using Python's itertools.groupby to count consecutive occurrences of elements as mentioned below

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]
sorted_data = sorted(data)
groups = groupby(sorted_data)

for key, group in groups:
   print(key, len(list(group)))
```

It produces the output as expected

```
1 2
2 1
3 3
4 1
5 2
```

But out of curiosity I tried to print the counts alone just to see what happens like below,

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]
sorted_data = sorted(data)
groups = groupby(sorted_data)

for group in groups:
   print(len(list(group)))
```

I get this response

```
2
2
2
2
2
```

I've encountered that the groupby function behaves differently when I try to print the counts alone versus when I print both the key and the count.

Why does groupby behave differently in these two cases? an explanation will be great.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your line

```
print(len(list(group)))
```

will always give 2. as group is a list of 2 items, where the first item is the index, and the second item is the iterator.

i.e. your group is

```
(1, <itertools._grouper object at 0x0000029681808220>)
```

Instead replace it with

```
print(len(list(list(group)[1])))
```

Comment: The `list()` around `group` is superfluous. You don't need to turn a tuple into a list to access it by index.

Comment: oh yea. how did i miss that. It can be just group[1] as well.